# Laravel Passport login not redirecting properly with Jetstream Inertia

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport, inertiajs

I have implemented an OAuth system with Laravel Passport, but the login and all authentication for this system is handled by Laravel Jetstream with Inertia.

When I want to request a code (using the Authorization Code Grant), my application redirects me to my OAuth server, this server asks me for login before continue, this screen is the screen generated by Laravel Jetstream login using Inertia (Vue). When I'm logged in, it redirects me to the authorization page, but this redirect is weird because this page is shown inside a Vue (Inertia) page, the URL in the browser doesn't update, and if I accept the authorization request it redirects me back to my application, but the redirect is inside the same Vue page, I mean, the URL is the same as my OAuth server login, but the view is my app who requested the code.

I think that there's a problem with redirections in Vue because the authorization page isn't using Inertia (is the default authorization page of Laravel Passport), and I don't know how to fix it, can you help me?

Here is an image:

[image: Bad Frame]

As you can see, it seems to be in a modal, but is an Inertia error page, and inside is showing the authorization page, is an redirect error that I don't know how to fix

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution ?

Comment: "As you can see" actually, I can't. If there was an image, it's been removed by now. That's why you should post it here as text directly. Can you do that?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem as you
I solved it as follows:

in file `AuthenticatedSessionController.php`

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming authentication request.
 *
 * @param  \App\Http\Requests\Auth\LoginRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 */
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    if ($request->session()->has('url.intended')) {
        return Inertia::location(session('url.intended'));
    }

    return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
}
```

Comment: Found this useful in a similar problem where I'm using multiple layouts for rootView, which wasn't changing after redirecting.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old issue - but I stumbled on this myself today and found this question being asked here - it gave me some info on how to solve it - but after checking the code some things seem to have changed in Laravel Jetstream/Fortify and below solution seems to be more accurate now and easier to implement as the mentioned `AuthenticatedSessionController.php` is inside the package and below can be done in user code without touching the package code itself.

---

I fixed this by overriding the used `*Reponse` classes which are used internally by Laravel Fortify, below are my two overrides in code:

The `LoginResponse` is needed for normal login flow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Responses\LoginResponse as LoginResponseBase;

class LoginResponse extends LoginResponseBase
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('url.intended')) {
            return Inertia::location(session('url.intended'));
        }

        return parent::toResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Add in `App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::register` the following line to override it (Don't forget the use statements):

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;
use App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse;
...
public function register()
{
    ...
    $this->app->singleton(LoginResponseContract::class, LoginResponse::class);
    ...
}
```

---

The `TwoFactorLoginResponse` is needed for when you use 2FA else this will break too in the same way as normal login does:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Inertia\Inertia;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Responses\TwoFactorLoginResponse as TwoFactorLoginResponseBase;

class TwoFactorLoginResponse extends TwoFactorLoginResponseBase
{
    /**
     * Create an HTTP response that represents the object.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        if ($request->session()->has('url.intended')) {
            return Inertia::location(session('url.intended'));
        }

        return parent::toResponse($request);
    }
}
```

Add in `App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::register` the following line to override it (Don't forget the use statements):

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\TwoFactorLoginResponse as TwoFactorLoginResponseContract;
use App\Http\Responses\TwoFactorLoginResponse;
...
public function register()
{
    ...
    $this->app->singleton(TwoFactorLoginResponseContract::class, TwoFactorLoginResponse::class);
    ...
}
```

Above changes just makes sure the correct response is given so Inertia handles the redirect correctly according to their docs:
https://inertiajs.com/redirects#external-redirects

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This is the most proper solution so far!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the default view for login action if the request coming from Inertia. You can do it in FortifyServiceProvider.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::loginView(function () {
            if (Request::inertia()) {
                return Inertia::location(url()->current());
            }
            return view('auth.login');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using inertia page , so instead of laravel's redirect syntax:

```
redirect($somewhere);
```

use

```
use Inertia\Inertia;

// .... skip

Inertia::location($somewhere);
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

Share my solution, using Custom authentication:
web.php

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'wechatLogin'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
Route::post('/logout', [LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

LoingController.php

```
...
    public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $credentials = $request->validate([
            'email' => ['required', 'email'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $request->session()->regenerate();
            return redirect(route('dashboard'));
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return Inertia::location('/');
    }
...
```